# how to text from url with xcode to a string

Tags: xcode, url, text, xcode3.2

```
NSURL *url;
            NSData *data;
            NSString *blork;
            url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.mycompanyaddress.com/identity_check.jsp?cliId=A-00000&security_key=00000"];
            data = [url resourceDataUsingCache: NO];
            blork = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];         
            UIAlertView *testMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"From Server: " message: blork  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [testMessage show];
            [testMessage release];
```

RESOURCEDATAUSINGCACHE is now a deprecated function..otherwise it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use -

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

and as document says

Use `NSURLConnection` instead of this method.

Comment: i want to display it in a label

Comment: you want to display "blork" in a label?

Comment: i am fairly new to xcode like 2 days new almost
so i just didnt grasp correctly how to use the NSURL conncection

Comment: yes and i succeeded.. but "resourceDataUsingCache" is a deprecated function :(

Comment: link for NSURLConnection - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: @saadnib thanks 
i tried using the connection but i just didn't have any success in reading the data.. 
am i suppose to implement all of the methods too? for a successful connection

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"http://dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php"];
 blork = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
 [nameLabel setText:blork];

Comment: you will get data in this one - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php"]]; 
 blork = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
 [nameLabel setText:blork];

Comment: you are using dataWithContentsOfURL:@"dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php" instead of dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php"]

Comment: thanks man, it atleast doesn't give an error anymore but it doesn't give any answer in either..label is still empty

Comment: just try to NSLog your blork as NSLog("%@",blork); before setting it to the label and check your console what are getting there.

Comment: passing argument 1 from incompatable pointer type is the warning it gives.. + where is the console in xcode?
sorry but i am used to working on .net and netbeans .. so this is fairly new to me

Comment: on which line you are getting this warning.

Comment: sorry for the late reply man, just after the NSLOG line
and i have a non-apple keyboard so it has no command button but thanks i'll check it from the options

Comment: i found the console but at the moment there is this warning there only

Comment: I don't think this warning is because of NSLog because we are using %@ for blork which is a NSString and %@ is format specifier for a NSString.

Comment: probably, i am trying to get data from
"you will get data in this one - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data – saadnib 2 hours ago"
as you said..but i get errors like...a lot..
i am having trouble following the class tutorial i guess right now

Comment: hi bilal i have checked it by running code at my end there is some problem with url, i have cross checked it for http://www.google.com and its working but not with your url

Comment: which one are you talking about?
i mean this code "u are using dataWithContentsOfURL:@"dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php" instead of dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php"] "
did it run a result full of text??????

Comment: it did run..i checked too..thanks man
i ll check that url again

Comment: NSURL *url;
 NSData *data;
 NSString *blork;
 url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"];
 data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 blork = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];         
 UIAlertView *testMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"From Server: " message: blork  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
 [testMessage show];
 [testMessage release];

Comment: o sorry..first time a forum..almost lol
i ll just do that then :)